# Async call to Authorize.net not working as expected in node.js

Tags: node.js

Im setting an Authorize.com charge as per their API reference at https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html in Node.js.

I can place both ACH and CC transactions just fine, but Im facing a problem with the response from Authorize. Their response takes about 1 second.

After all the parameters such as CC number, expiration date, etc are filled out, I execute a function as follows (ctrl.execute(function () {}):

```
var ctrl = new ApiControllers.CreateTransactionController(createRequest.getJSON());
ctrl.execute(function () {
var apiResponse = ctrl.getResponse();
var response = new ApiContracts.CreateTransactionResponse(apiResponse);
if (response != null) {
    if (response.getMessages().getResultCode() == ApiContracts.MessageTypeEnum.OK) {
        if (response.getTransactionResponse().getMessages() != null) {
            //transaction approved
            AuthorizeResult.status = 1;

         }
        else {
            //transaction rejected
            if (response.getTransactionResponse().getErrors() != null) {
                AuthorizeResult.status = 0;
             }
        }
    }
    else {
        if (response.getTransactionResponse() != null && response.getTransactionResponse().getErrors() != null) {
            AuthorizeResult.status = 0;
        }
        else {
   
            AuthorizeResult.status = 0;
        }
    }
}
else {
    AuthorizeResult.status = 0;
}
```

After I get a result from Authorize, I need to run this code, which Im unable to do, and if I place the code inside the function, I get an error:

> ```
> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
> at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
> ```

```
sqlString = `
        insert into AuthorizeBillings (memberid, datetime, authorizeid, messagecode, status, amount, billingtype, errorcode)
        values (@memberid, @datetime, @authorizeid, @messagecode, @status, @amount, @billingtype, @errorcode )`
        try {
            const pool = await utils.poolPromise
            const recordset = await pool.request()
                .input('memberid', utils.sql.Int, memberid)
                .....
                .....
                .input('errorcode', utils.sql.NVarChar, AuthorizeResult.errorcode)
                .query(sqlString)
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
```

I tried to run this function await but I had no luck. What I need is to continue the code execution AFTER this function returned a value, which I am not able to accomplish properly.

Thanks.

Comment: You said you already tried to run this function with async await. Could you show your code for that? async await is the solution here, perhaps you simply misapplied it.

Comment: Hello Silencedogood. I placed await ctrl.execute(function () {}

Comment: Using async await negates the need for callbacks. You'll need to refactor your code slightly. Otherwise, the code you want to execute after the api call will need to be within the callback.

Comment: My problem is that I do several async calls after a successful response, and the code above does not allow me to do that. That is why Im lost. Im placing my database call code and edit my question now. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend consolidating your code to a minimal example, without all the extra stuff. Simply code the api calls, with console.logs in between, so that you can test execution flow. It would have the added benefit of making it easier for me (us) to help.

Comment: There it is :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't a proper answer... But maybe it will help you out. In order to use `await`, you have to declare the function as `async`. So, something like this will allow async workflow:

```
async function AuthorizeTrans() { // Notice async declaration
   var ctrl = new ApiControllers.CreateTransactionController(createRequest.getJSON());
     var AuthorizeResult = {
     memberid: memberid,
     .....
     .....
     errorcode: ""
    }
    const res = await ctrl.execute(); // You can now use await
    var apiResponse = await res.getResponse();
    
    ....... // Rest of code...

    SqlExecute(params);
}

async function SqlExecute(params) {
    sqlString = `
    insert into AuthorizeBillings (memberid, datetime, authorizeid, messagecode, status, amount, billingtype, errorcode)
    values (@memberid, @datetime, @authorizeid, @messagecode, @status, @amount, @billingtype, @errorcode )`
    try {
        const pool = await utils.poolPromise
        const recordset = await pool.request()
            .input('memberid', utils.sql.Int, memberid)
            .....
            .....
            .input('errorcode', utils.sql.NVarChar, AuthorizeResult.errorcode)
            .query(sqlString)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

If you follow the logic from that syntax, you should be on the right track.

Comment: That works silencedogood if I place the code for updating the database inside the function, you are right, my problem is when I try to run the code outside that function (right below it). In your example, I can do const pool = await utils.poolPromise just fine, but the ideal scenario would be to be able to call the database after authorize response, from outside the function itself (since there are several calls to perform depending on the transaction status returned by authorize.

Comment: @Danielle Maybe I'm missing something... But couldn't you just create a method and pass the params for the query, then call the method after everything runs via `await`? In my example code you'd have to modify for params obviously....

Comment: Hummm... I guess may work. I will try it out in a few minutes.

Comment: Don't forget to declare async for the function with the query.

Comment: Thanks silencedogood!

Comment: @Danielle No problem. Always remember as a general rule: the more concise you can make your question, the easier it is for us to help. Happy coding :)